# MongoDB / C# Driver and Memory Issue

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using MongoDB 1.8.2 (Debian) and mongo-csharp-driver 1.1.0.4184 (IIS 7.5/.Net 4.0 x64).

Multiple items are inserted every second in a existing collection with ~ 3,000,000 objects (~ 1.9 GB).
The WebServer memory is increasing by ~ 1 MB after every insert -> which leads very fast to > 2 GB memory usage.
The memory is never released anymore and only an application pool recycle can free the memory.

Any ideas?

```
MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(mongoDBConnectionString);
MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase(dbName);                

MongoCollection<Result> resultCollection = database.GetCollection<Result>("Result");
resultCollection.Insert(result);
```

result looks like

```
private class Result
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }            
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public int Location { get; set; }            
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

My problem is not the insert, it's the select - sorry weird codebase to investigate ;-)

I reproduced it with this sample Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Start - " + GC.GetTotalMemory(false).ToString("#,###,##0") + " Bytes");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(mongoDBConnectionString);
    MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase(dbName);

    MongoCollection<Result> resultCollection = database.GetCollection<Result>("Result");
    var query = Query.And ( Query.EQ("Location", 1), Query.GTE("Timestamp", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90)) );

    MongoCursor<Result> cursor = resultCollection.FindAs<Result>(query);

    foreach (Result result in cursor)
    {
        // NOOP
    }

    Console.WriteLine(i + " - " + GC.GetTotalMemory(false).ToString("#,###,##0") + " Bytes");
}
```

Output from a .Net 4.0 **Console Application** with 10.000 results in the cursor:

```
Start - 193.060 Bytes
0 - 12.736.588 Bytes
1 - 24.331.600 Bytes
2 - 16.180.484 Bytes
3 - 13.223.036 Bytes
4 - 30.974.892 Bytes
5 - 13.335.236 Bytes
6 - 13.439.448 Bytes
7 - 13.942.436 Bytes
8 - 14.026.108 Bytes
9 - 14.113.352 Bytes
```

Output from a .Net 4.0 **Web Application** with the same 10.000 results in the cursor:

```
Start - 5.258.376 Bytes 
0 - 20.677.816 Bytes
1 - 29.893.880 Bytes
2 - 43.783.016 Bytes
3 - 20.921.280 Bytes
4 - 34.814.088 Bytes
5 - 48.698.704 Bytes
6 - 62.576.480 Bytes
7 - 76.453.728 Bytes
8 - 90.347.360 Bytes
9 - 104.232.800 Bytes
```

**RESULT:**

Bug was reported to 10gen and they will fix it in ***version >= 1.4*** (they are working currently on 1.2)!!!

Comment: Are you closing the MongoServer / MongoDatabase connections after each batch of inserts?

Comment: No need to close MongoServer / MongoDatabase connections because of actual connections to mongodb driver handle automatically through internal connections pool.

Comment: No, I don't close the connection.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, I'd suggest reporting it to 10gen.

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Threadsafety) you should create one instance of MongoServer for one server you connected to:

> MongoServer class
>
> This class serves as the root object for working with a MongoDB
>   server. You will create one instance of this class for each server you
>   connect to.

So you need only one instance of MongoServer. This should solve your memory leaks issue.

I suggest to use [dependency injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163739.aspx) ([unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/), [structure map](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/), ..) to register MongoServer instance in container as singletone or just use classic [singletone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) pattern for MongoServer. If you new in dependency injection you can take a look in Martin Fowler [article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

**Update:**

Probably issue was not in mongodb c# driver. I've made following testing:

w7, iis 7.5, same c# driver, same mongodb:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3000000; i++)
{
   MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost:27020");
   MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("mpower_read");

   MongoCollection<Result> resultCollection = 
                              database.GetCollection<Result>("results");

   resultCollection.Insert(new Result()
   {
     _id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(),
     Content = i.ToString(),
     Location = i,
     Timestamp = DateTime.Now
   });
}
```

I've even run this test 3 times and server not eat memory at all. So...

Comment: I changed it to a Singleton Pattern but with the same behavior, because MongoServer.Create will only create one instance. 
Documentation of MongoServer.Create -> Creates a new instance or returns an existing instance of MongoServer. Only one instance is created for each combination of server settings.

Comment: @mac866: Okay i'll do then some testing tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: pls make an aspx Page which only inserts 1 Row into your collection & call this Page many times via e.g. wget - and if possible with concurrent users. I also don't have a problem with your scenario - 1 Request with 3,000,000 inserts. thx!!!